# Wordpress performance (Slow queries)

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, performance

can someone help me with wp queries? Our website is slow. We noticed that there are two queries with long query time. I need to find what is using this queries. Here is queries from log:

```
# Query_time: 21.955256 Lock_time: 1.873010 Rows_sent: 3 Rows_examined: 3356082
SELECT wposts.* FROM wp_posts wposts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wposts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE wposts.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY wposts.ID
ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 3;

# Query_time: 7.584517 Lock_time: 0.000062 Rows_sent: 3 Rows_examined: 100621
SET timestamp=1390921247;
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'views' ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC LIMIT 0, 3;
```

More info:
WP 3.8.1

Plugins:
 - Advanced Custom Fields
 - Audio player
 - Avatars
 - Broken Link Checker
 - Capability Manager
 - Cron GUI
 - DB Cache Reloaded Fix
 - FV WordPress Flowplayer
 - Google XML Sitemaps
 - Hide Categories
 - NextGEN Gallery
 - Query Monitor
 - Scissors
 - Simple Image Sizes
 - ThemeSmith
 - Theme Test Drive
 - TweetMeme Retweet Button
 - User Avatar
 - video-flv-converter
 - Vixy YouTube Embed
 - WordPress Database Ping
 - WP-EMail
 - WP-Optimize
 - WP-Paginate
 - WP-Polls
 - WP-PostViews
 - Tabulky
 - WP Image Size Limit
 - WP Minify
 - WP Super Cache
 - Youtuber

I deactived All in one SEO pack becuase I found this plugin is reason why websites is slow but looks like our website is still slow.

We have published 19650 post and 167 categories.

Theme is super simple and P3 (plugin performance profiler) show very nice load time for theme.

We have 141 queries on HP, 162 queries in the article, 113 queries in the category.

any help much appreciate

BTW: I am sorry my english is not a good

Comment: Please use the `EXPLAIN` statement to get the execution plan for these queries and add it to the question, so we can see what indexes exist and if they are being used.

Comment: Also, in the first query you have a bunch of left joins, but don't actually select any columns from them and in the end group by post ID. It would seem you can just remove the joins without having any effect on the results.

Comment: Did you make sure the indexes are set correctly on the relevant tables?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the important query which wordpress will execute to list the published post.As your query output says that there are 100621 records in your wordpress , so you must have enabled caching in mysql as well as wordpress. If there are lots of pending/draft post , kindly take the backup and remove them.

For mysql debug you should enable the profiling for time being and execute the query manually.

**To enable profiling**

SET profiling = 1;

**Then execute your Query.**

**SHOW PROFILES;**
you see a list of queries the profiler has statistics for. And finally you choose which query to examine with

**SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;**

my query output

mysql> SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000040 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000013 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000118 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000012 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000010 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000009 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000012 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000052 |
| System lock                    | 0.000021 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000036 |
| init                           | 0.000073 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000025 |
| statistics                     | 0.000065 |
| preparing                      | 0.000035 |
| Creating tmp table             | 0.000539 |
| Sorting for group              | 0.000018 |
| executing                      | 0.000010 |
| Copying to tmp table           | 0.025823 |
| Sorting result                 | 0.000800 |
| Sending data                   | 0.000065 |
| end                            | 0.000009 |
| removing tmp table             | 0.000144 |
| end                            | 0.000012 |
| query end                      | 0.000011 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000024 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000037 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000007 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000008 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
28 rows in set (0.02 sec)

Regards

Suyash

http://linuxhacks.in